# Dynamic side menu List for Login service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

I am trying to create bootstrap navbar menus dynamically using Angular 7. every user login response receives dynamic menu list in response I'm using BehaviorSubject it loaded before login so empty json [image]

```
login(username) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`http://100.55.5.122:8080/Auto/login`,  JSON.stringify(username),  {observe: 'response'} )
            .pipe(map(user =>  {
                this.myData.next(user.body.menuDetails);
                return user;
            }));
    }
```

I created in Injectable service menulist.ts I received JSON form login success response how to integrate responses JSON in menulist.ts reference attached image responses login success

```
  const menulist = [
      {
        label: 'Menu List',
        main: [

          {
            state: 'user-management',
            name: 'User Management',

            icon: 'feather icon-user',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'user-profile',
                name: 'User Profile'
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
    ];
    @Injectable()
    export class MenuItems {
      constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.authenticationService.myData.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
  });
      }
      getAll(): Menu[] {
        return menulist;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz Code?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: tried BehaviorSubject loaded before login so empty json